# turn off or ignore neurons in pytorch in neural networks

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, dropout

I want to build a feed forward-neural network and train it (to **overfitt**) on a small portion of the input features. For this I used dropout regularization as it follows the logic on training on small portion and then test model on the whole features (Turning off during training and turn on test).

But since I am interested on overfitting, I don't think dropout is a good solution for me. So how can I turn off  some input nodes during training in the same way as used in Dropout regularization, but this time I don't want *randomly* turn them off, but chose which featured will be ignored during training ?

Comment: Is this for a network you've built? If so, during your `forward()` pass you could try multiplying your activations by `0` or `1` to "turn them off".

Comment: Yes I am trying to built a network this way, but if I did that it would ignore features also on test set. I need to turn them off only when training, like we do on dropout regularisation.

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to have a `train` flag. When it's `true` you multiply by your custom dropout layers, when it's `false` you do not. I'd be a little concerned about the distribution changing during test though. You may have to scale your activations for this the same way dropout does

Comment: Mmm, if I can rephrase your answer. I want to turn off some of the **input neurons** during training, I would multiply during `forward()` the input `x` with a vector of 1s and 0s where 1s are indices of the inputs I want to ignore, right ?

Comment: The opposite, `0` would represent the inputs you wish to ignore. Eg. For `input=[3,5,7]` you would multiply by `[1,0,1]` to get `[3,0,7]` and ignore the middle value. At test time you would multiply by `[1,1,1]` but I'm fairly sure you would still have to account for the change in distribution. See: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/44293/how-dropout-work-during-testing-in-neural-network

Comment: One alternative could be, masking !

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
for param in model.parameters():
  param.requires_grad = False
```

to turn off layers in the model